# Windows 10 I can't search Anything in 'standard app's'

Tags: windows-10

So i accidently set notepad as a standard app for something and i can't change it again.

Though now i need to change it to something that isn't a 'app' in the appstore and i can't search everything in i click on it to change it.
I have tried to look for answears on the internet and can't find anything to change the setting's.

Can someone help me here then?? Cause i can't find a way to change it to something that isn't a app in the appstore.